# Dropping items based on communalities in factor analysis

Tags: correlation, factor-analysis

I have been asked to rerun my exploratory FA (EFA) of an istrument which originally comprised five factors with five items pertaining to each dimension (factor). In this regard, I have been asked to do EFA of the instrument, inspect the communalities and drop items according to a threshold (and re-run this process until the acceptable communalities are reached) before dropping items based on factor loadings. My question is: What threshold would be appropriate for such practice and are there any references for this?

Comment: Here's a reference, although it's in the context of PCA: "Communalities less than 0.5 can be considered to be too low, as this would mean that the variable shares less than half of its variability in common with the other variables." page 109, Daniel T. Larose and Chantal D. Larose, Data Mining and Predictive Analytics, 2nd edition. Wiley, 2015.

Comment: I'd be careful, though. A variable with low communality might not belong in the factor structure, but may be very important to keep around for the overall research project. For example, suppose you were surveying restaurant patrons and had many questions about the service, many questions about the atmosphere of the restaurant, but only one question about food quality. That question about food quality might have low communality, but still be important in assessing the restaurant.

Comment: It is not a good very good advice to drop items with not high communality. An item can be loaded only by one factor, say, loading 0.5, which is not bad for most of social sciences. Then its communality (if there was no oblique rotation) is 0.5^2=0.25 "only".

Comment: Ask the person who told you to do this.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. We found a paper in which the editor employed the described procedure using .3 as a threshold for low communalities.

Comment: @user175214, kindly share the link of the paper that describes .3 as a threshold for low communalitlies

Comment: see related question https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/596635/3277