# How does one evaluate/interpret "appreciable" communalities for each variable (i.e., scale item) when using exploratory factor analysis?

Tags: modeling, factor-analysis

I have a question regarding communalities when doing factor analysis.

I understand the concept of communalities (e.g., its a function of variance, like R^2, as in they look at how much variance in the latent factor is explained by that item) and how they relate to uniqueness (e.g., 1-communalities = Uniqueness; the variance that is unique to the variable and not shared with other variables).

First, assume I have a set of 25 scale items, with the five supposed "factors" (e.g., big five personalities) represented by five items each. Using psych:: in R, we conduct a parallel analysis; for our sake, let's assume that parallel suggests a five-factor model. We fit a five-factor EFA model, using maximum likelihood and a promax rotation. The output indicates that the five-factor model fits the data well based on absolute fit (RMSEA <= .08) and relative fit (TMI >= .95). The communalities (for the sake of this hypothetical example) stretched anywhere from .19 to .70 for each of the 25-items.

Initially, I attempted to find some metric or barometer for judging what could be interpreted as an "appreciable" communality. There were some references in the context of strictly PCA that referred to it being >.50 and even dropping items lower than this (see [Dropping items based on communalities in factor analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/300168/dropping-items-based-on-communalities-in-factor-analysis)). Other internet searches have suggested that "acceptable" ranges from .25-.40 while "good" is around .70 (see random discussion here https://www.researchgate.net/post/What-is-the-communality-cut-off-value-in-EFA).

Based on what I have found, it appears that this barometer for judging an "appreciable" communality is somewhat subjective, given my lack of success in finding anything concrete with a citation/reference in the context of a factor analysis. Wondering if any of you may have any wisdom to share!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `as in they look at how much variance in the latent factor is explained by that item` No. Communality is the portion of the item's variance explained by all the common factors. The rest portion is called uniqueness of the item.

Comment: On an abstract theoretical level, communality can be any in 0 -100% range, and won't violate FA model or "quality". But on the practical side, there is at least a couple of points for "large communality is preferable" suggestion. First, obvious, in case we are doing FA for designing tests/questionnaires, we are not interested in items _irrelevant_ to what the instrument is meant to measure, i.e. items with high uniqueness, away from the "packs". Second, less obvious, high communality of items demands a lesser _sample size_ for FA to be able to uncover population factors correctly.